# C++ Beginner Assignment Operators

Tags: c++, operators, variable-assignment

i'm a beginner in C++ and i'm doing this example code of assignment operators. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 200; int y = 100;
    x += y; cout << x << endl; //x += y; // x = x + y, x = 200 + 100, output 300.
    x -= y; cout << x << endl; //x -= y; // x = x - y, x = 200 - 100, output 100.
    x /= y; cout << x << endl; //x /= y; // x = x / y, x = 200 / 100, output 2.
    x %= y; cout << x << endl; //x % y; // x = % y, x = 200 % 100, output 0.
    return 0;
}
```

i'm getting the results for

```
x -= y = 200
x /= y = 2
x %= y = 2
```

when its suppose to be

```
x -= y = 100
x /= y = 2
x %= y = 0
```

its actually adding up the previous results. How do i stop the code from adding the result to the next line? Thanks!

Comment: You're assuming `x` resets back to 200 after every command, but it doesn't.

Comment: Stop asking it to accumulate the results. `-=`, `+=`, `/=` and `%=` are all accumulation operators that assign the result of the operation before the `=` to the variable on the left.

Comment: your first assignment is `x += y` so that the next one `x -= y` results in `x == 200`. There is no "adding up" of results, you just keep assigning to `x`, if this is not what you want, then just dont do it...

Comment: Just define xstart as 200 and reset x to xstart before every operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the original value of `x` and `y` to be kept forever, but it isn't. Assignments like `x += y;` or `x = x + y;` change the value of the variables (in this case `x`, that is, the one on the left side of the equal sign). The previous value is overwritten and therefore lost.

If you don't want to change the original values, you have to either assign the result to other variables (for example, one called `temp`, that you can overwrite every time), or you don't assign it at all, and you simply send to `cout` the result of the calculation.

As an example with a temp variable:

```
int x = 200; int y = 100; int temp;
temp = x + y; cout << temp << endl; //temp = x + y, temp = 200 + 100, output 300.
temp = x - y; cout << temp << endl; //temp = x - y, temp = 200 - 100, output 100.
```

Or, doing away with variables entirely:

```
cout << x + y << endl; // 200 + 100, output 300
cout << x - y << endl; // 200 - 100, output 100
```

Another way to see that the variables are overwritten (well, in this case it's only `x`) is to declare them as `const`:

```
const int x = 200; const int y = 100;
```

The program won't compile, because it tries to change constant variables.

Answer (score 3):

When `x` and `y` are variables and `U` is an operation `x U= y` is equivalent to:

```
x = x U y;
```

which means the original variable is being modified and assigned with the result.

You code is equivalent to:

```
x = x + y;
cout << x << endl; // x is now 300
x = x - y;
cout << x << endl; // x is now 200
x = x / y;
cout << x << endl; // x is now 2
x = x % y;
cout << x << endl; // x is now 2
```

If you want not to change `x` you want can save `x` in a temporary variable or just print the result:

```
int x = 200;
int y = 100;
cout << x - y << endl; // x unchanged
cout << x + y << endl; // x unchanged
cout << x / y << endl; // x unchanged
cout << x * y << endl; // x unchanged
```

Or:

```
int x = 200;
int x = 100;
int result = x + y;
cout << result << endl;
result = x - y;
cout << x << endl;
result = x / y;
cout << result << endl;
result = x % y;
cout << result << endl;
```

*Note: since the `=` operator returns the value after the assignment `cout << x += y << end` can compile and print the assigned value.*

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in your comments in your code, the result of `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`, which means the value of `x` will change. So it is no surprise that the new value of `x`, 300, is used in the next mathematical assignment.

If you want to avoid that, consider saving the result of `x + y` to another variable.

```
int x = 200;
int y = 100;
int x_addition = x + y;
std::cout << x_addition << std::endl;
```

Or, if its only usage is in displaying the result of the addition, do it all in one line.

```
int x = 200;
int y = 100;
std::cout << x + y << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you are doing assignment like `x += y;`, it changing the value of x.

```
x += y;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + y;
```

Which means assignment. Value of x is changing. It's now 300. Same thing happening for latter assignments too.

*Note:* if you don't want to change the value of x and y, better do the assignments in other variable.

```
int x = 200, y = 100, t;
t = x + y; cout << t << endl;
t = x - y; cout << t << endl;
t = x * y; cout << t << endl;
t = (int) x / y; cout << t << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting x back to 200 after each assignment.  Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 200; int y = 100;
    x += y; cout << x << endl; 
    x = 200;
    x /= y; cout << x << endl; 
    x = 200;
    x %= y; cout << x << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the accumulation operators so you're changing the value of 'x'.

```
x += y; // x = 200 + 100 = 300
x -= y; // x = 300 - 100 = 200
x /= y; // x = 200 / 100 = 2
x %= y; // x = 2 % 100 = 2
```

Instead you could do:

```
    int x = 200;
    int y = 100;
    cout << x + y << endl;
    cout << x - y << endl;
    cout << x / y << endl;
    cout << x % y << endl;
```

Or:

```
    int x = 200;
    int y = 100;
    int result;

    result = x + y;
    cout << result << endl;

    result = x - y;
    cout << result << endl;

    result = x / y;
    cout << result << endl;

    result = x % y;
    cout << result << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not counting on Addition operations value

```
x=200,y=100;    
x+=y;//x=200+100=300,x=300,y=100   
x-=y;//x=300-100=200,x=200,y=100
```

Here you are forgetting that there is **ADDITION** OPERATION before subtraction